# Executing cargo:run from a maven profile

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-cargo

I am trying to write a maven `profile` that will run the `cargo:run` `goal` and will Start a container and wait for the user to press `CTRL + C` to stop. However when I run `mvn clean install -PstartApplication`, the command completes successfully without waiting. What am I missing?

```
<profile>
   <id>startApplication</id>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <wait>true</wait>
               <container>
                  <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                  <type>installed</type>
                  <home>${catalina.home}</home>
               </container>
               <configuration>
                  <type>standalone</type>
                  <home>${project.basedir}/target/tomcat7x</home>
               </configuration>
               <deployables>
                  <deployable>
                     <properties>
                        <context>ROOT</context>
                     </properties>
                     <groupId>com.demo.web</groupId>
                     <artifactId>sample-web-app</artifactId>
                     <type>war</type>
                  </deployable>
               </deployables>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <id>start-container</id>
                     <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                     </goals>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the plugin configuration: the `executions` element in the code you posted is within the `configuration` element, which is not correct and as such it will be ignored by Maven. (Check the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) for more details).
The `executions` section should be out of a `configuration` section (and at the same nested level). They could then also include a further `configuration` section, which will be the configuration used by that specific wrapping `execution`, while the previous would be a more generic configuration applied by default to all listed executions.

In this specific case, the Cargo Plugin also [provides](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html#Maven2PluginReferenceGuide-features) a further `configuration` element within the Maven `configuration` section, which makes things a bit confusing and misleading (a different name should have been chosen, in my opinion).

Hence, in your case, you should move out the `executions` section from the `configuration` section, as following:

```
<profile>
   <id>startApplication</id>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <wait>true</wait>
               <container>
                  <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                  <type>installed</type>
                  <home>${catalina.home}</home>
               </container>
               <configuration>
                  <type>standalone</type>
                  <home>${project.basedir}/target/tomcat7x</home>
               </configuration>
               <deployables>
                  <deployable>
                     <properties>
                        <context>ROOT</context>
                     </properties>
                     <groupId>com.demo.web</groupId>
                     <artifactId>sample-web-app</artifactId>
                     <type>war</type>
                  </deployable>
               </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>start-container</id>
                 <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                 </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```